# Expand/Collapse apex:pageblocktable rows in visualforce to display corresponding child records underneath each row

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to do exactly [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099O4IAI), but can't get it to work. [This](http://www.forcetree.com/2010/04/expand-collapse-pageblock-table-columns.html?showComment=1446482825003) solution comes close, but doesn't seem to be super elegant because when the child records are shown, the parent table columns get pushed over to the right and it looks ugly. It would be awesome if we could display the child apex:pageblocktable UNDER the parent row spanning across the entire parent table width.

I tried to create a html table within pageblocktable with two rows: one to hold the actual row, another to hold the toggle'able child record stack; but no luck. Can someone please advise how to tweak [the sample above](http://www.forcetree.com/2010/04/expand-collapse-pageblock-table-columns.html?showComment=1446482825003) to accomplish what I am trying to do? Thanks a lot!

Also, both parent and child records must be editable. That is, they must allow apex:inlineEditSupport.